# Passing DateTime with Bound Properties on Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, properties, razor-pages

I have been trying to get started with Razor Pages.

I have 2 pages for as part of a booking app:

1. Search Page
2. Book Page

Bookings and room availability is written / fetched from a SQL database (localdb)

I am in Australia and my computer region settings display dates dd-MM-yyyy.

I am using bound properties ( a new concept for me) and i got the search page working fine and the StartDate / EndDate is displayed in the correct format and the searc works in the database, however, when i go to the booking page the dates go to (01/01/0001).  For some reason the dates try to convert to US format MM-dd-yyyy when going from the search page to the booking page and as today is the 13th of July it thinks the month is wrong and causes a spill.  Wotks fine until the 12th day of the month.

An easy way to fix this is to change my PC region to US and date format to "MM-dd-yyyy" but i want to learn how to handle multiple date format's and regions within my web page.

Is there a way to make this property consistent between pages? or set the format of the property in the booking page to be the same as the search page?

The best i can find by searching is parsing the date as a string, reformatting it and storing it in the database as a string, then extracting it as a string and converting to DateTime as needed, however this sounds needlessly complicated and rife for downstream problems.

HTML for search page

```
<h1>Room Search</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.StartDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.StartDate" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.EndDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.EndDate" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>


@if (Model.AvailableRoomTypes?.Count > 0)
{
    <br />
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room Type</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Nights</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var room in Model.AvailableRoomTypes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>@room.Title</strong><br />
                        @room.Description
                    </td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C}", room.Price)</td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:0}", (Model.EndDate - Model.StartDate).Days)</td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C}", room.Price * (Model.EndDate - Model.StartDate).Days)</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/BookRoom" asp-route-roomtypeid="@room.Id" 
                           asp-route-startdate="@Model.StartDate"
                           asp-route-enddate="@Model.EndDate">Book Now</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

HTML.cs for search page

```
        public class RoomSearchModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseData _db;

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public bool SearchEnabled { get; set; } = false;

        public List<RoomTypeModel> AvailableRoomTypes { get; set; }

        public RoomSearchModel(IDatabaseData db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

            //StartDate = DateTimeCheck.ParseRequestDate(StartDate);
            //EndDate = DateTimeCheck.ParseRequestDate(EndDate);

            if (SearchEnabled == true)
            {
                if (EndDate > StartDate)
                {
                    AvailableRoomTypes = _db.GetAvailableRoomTypes(StartDate, EndDate);
                }
                else
                {
                    AvailableRoomTypes = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage(new 
            { 
                SearchEnabled = true, 
                StartDate = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
                EndDate = EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            });
        }
    }
```

HTML for booking page

```
<h1>Book Room</h1>

<h2>@Model.RoomType.Title</h2>
<p>
    @Model.RoomType.Description
</p>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.LastName" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
</form>
```

HTML.cs for booking page

```
public class BookRoomModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IDatabaseData _db;
    //CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");


    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public RoomTypeModel RoomType { get; set; }

    public BookRoomModel(IDatabaseData db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (RoomTypeId > 0)
        {

            if (EndDate == DateTime.MinValue || StartDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                RoomType = _db.GetRoomTypeById(RoomTypeId);
            }
            
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        _db.BookGuest(FirstName, LastName, StartDate, EndDate, RoomTypeId);
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993584/asp-net-mvc-apply-different-displayformats-for-edit-and-display-modes or you can `.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(...)` a `IDisplayMetadataProvider` to set the `.DisplayMetadata.DisplayFormatString` 
 `.DisplayMetadata.EditFormatString` for all datetime properties.

Comment: Note that your `.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM")` is definitely going to give the wrong value.

Comment: Will edit this, should be yyyy-MM-dd as that was what the console inside chrome was asking for.   I was had just tried this to see what would happen.  Same result.

Comment: Do you want to the Time format based on locale? You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258761/time-format-based-on-locale-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: How do you pass data from `RoomSearchModel` to `booking`? You just use RedirectToPage() but you don't specity whitch page you need to redirect.

Comment: that is in the room search HTML <td><a asp-page="/BookRoom" asp-route-roomtypeid="@room.Id"

Comment: I can create a separate string from the datetime, pass it to the booking page then parse it, just seems like an unnecessary workaround

Comment: I am afraid you need to do that.